# Georeferencing batch geotagged photos

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, georeferencing, aerial-photography, orthorectification

I am struggling with georeferencing over 300 aerial photographs. All of those photographs are geotagged and generally are rather easy to georeference but I am wandering if that can be done automatically?

What I know:
 - xy position for every photo (one point)
 - all of the photos were taken in similar distance (from 88 - 92 meters interval)
 - all of them has the same size, format and pixel size

I was thinking about georeferencing one picture and then use the same link points for the next photo but the problem is I don't know how to make it to get the enough precision.

When I tried to use the same link points for the next picture it worked well, so the photo was well georeferenced but in the wrong place (good shape but the location of previous photo) that's why I thought about moving that link points, maybe depending on loacation of those yellow points representing picture location?

Is there any way to joixn all the photos into one raster or anything which will let me make the georeferencing faster or automatically?
[image: each point represents the single photo location][image: one georeferenced image]

Answer (score 2):

This will not help you in ArcMap but ArcGIS Pro (which is part of the ArcGIS Desktop license) will be worth investigating for [Georeferencing a raster automatically to another raster](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/georeferencing-a-raster-automatically-to-another-raster.htm):

> Auto Georeference allows you to automatically
>   georeference your raster dataset to a referenced raster dataset. The
>   automated control points are based on the spectral signatures of
>   different locations across your image, so it is meant for aerial and
>   satellite imagery which are similar in nature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

To complete this task I've used agisoft photoscan. It gave me very good results with quick data turn around. It not only made a batch georeferencing, I could also create a DEM layer from a hundreds of photos in a minutes, so I would recommend that software!